# Is it possible to convert a qudit to a qubit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

I am trying to write a Qiskit code for a algorithm which uses qudits. I want to use qubits instead because $p$ value can go pretty high. Is it mathematically possible to convert qudit to qubit for this purpose?

Comment: You can always use log_2(d) qubits to represent a qudit. E.g., for 5 states use $|0\rangle \mapsto |000\rangle$, $|1\rangle \mapsto |001\rangle$ and so on. The overhead is, at most, twofold.  The mappings of gates may be a bit annoying, though

Comment: what do you mean with "convert" exactly? You cannot convert a generic qudit into a qubit and hope to faithfully retrieve the originally information, as a qudit holds more info than a qubit. But if you have a state spanned by only two qudit states, you can certainly remap ("encode") these into a single qubit.

Comment: protocol uses qudits to transmit data. mathematically protocol is efficient. Paper is mathematical in nature and I am trying to see if protocol can be implemented on quantum computer. Issue here is d-value can rise very high since protocol uses Shamir's Secret sharing and d needs to be high in realistic conditions. I was thinking of using qubits to transmit data instead.